# Cannot load different View Controllers from a single UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am trying a single button to load different view controllers 
The action for the **start**  button is this:

```
-(IBAction)startApp:(id)sender{
    switch (menuItem) {
      case 1:
        [self openPage1];

        break;
       case 2:
        [self openPage2];

        break;
       case 3:
        [self openPage3];

        break;
       case 4:
        [self openPage4];

        break;
       default:
        break;
  }

}
```

The values of **menuItem** is set elsewhere and theres no problem with it.
The functions in the switch cases are also called upon correctly on different values of menuItem.

```
-(void)openPage1{
   Page1 * myPage1 = [[Page1 alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myPage1 animated:YES];

}

-(void)openPage2{
   Page2 *myPage2 = [[Page2    alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myPage2 animated:YES];

}

-(void)openPage3{
   Page3 *myPage3 = [[TableViewController alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myPage3 animated:YES];
}

-(void)openPage4{
   Page4  *myPage4 = [[Page4  alloc]init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:myPage4 animated:YES];
}
```

I imported all the .h files of the view controllers , so that is not the problem.

The problem is all the **openPage#()** methods are executing, but the pages i.e the View Controllers, are not loaded on pressing the start button.

Comment: What does happen when you press the start button? Nothing, or does it go to a blank view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar happens nothing. The method is called , but the statements inside the methods are not executing

Answer (score 1):

Does the view controller actually have a navigation controller? Place a debug point in one of the openPage# methods and check if `self.navigationController` is nil.

You can do so by typing `po self.navigationController` in the console while the debugger is stopped in the method.

You cannot use the navigationController property if you do not have the view controller embedded in a navigation controller. If it is nil, do 1 of 2 things:

---

Use `[self presentViewController:myPage# animated:YES];` This will animate the view controller up modally.

---

Put your current view controller into a navigation controller. I don't know how your current view controller is being presented, but basically instead of presenting just the view controller, you first wrap it in a UINavigationController. Assuming this view controller is the root view controller being setup in the app delegate:

```
MyViewController *myController = [MyViewController new];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:navController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

Comment: You mean to say the self view controller should be embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: yes it is nil. how to instantiate it ? am I selecting the wrong property for the self view controller?

Comment: I updated my answer to include 2 ways of fixing the problem. Basically you can't use the navigationController property unless it is embedded in a navigation controller. So you can either embed it in one, or you can present it modally instead of through the navigation controller.